# Is it possible to have a good crust without prebaking a quiche?

Tags: baking, crust, french-cuisine, quiche, blind-baking

I'm planning on making a quiche (Lorraine with leek to be exact) and I was looking up recipes for quiches. Most recipes call for blind-baking the crust in advance (or at least partly), but some skip this step and pour the filling in the raw dough and bake it like that.

I think blind-baking would prevent the dough from getting soggy since the filling is quite liquid. The other recipes look nice (judging on the picture), but won't the dough be soggy?
Or should you put the temperature lower and the time higher so the liquid can evaporate?

Does it matter whether you blind-bake your crust for a quiche? Or does it mainly depend on the type of dough (puff, shortcrust...)? Or on the amount of liquid or type of veggie/meat (precooked)? Any other factors that I don't think of?

Comment: This question is part of our contest. See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/its-french-cuisine-time-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal cooking time of a quiche (20 to 30 minutes), the crust doesn't really get soggy from the filling, even if it is quite liquid, as is expected for quiche Lorraine. So, you can without problem cook your quiche without first blind-baking the crust. The difference will be in the crispness of the crust: if you try to get it crispy, you should prebake, if you don't mind it being rather, well, “plain”, you don't.

The only real reason for me to blind-bake a crust is when you put something on it that won't be cooked (tartelettes), that will only get grilled or that will be baked less that it would require to bake the crust (meringue tart). Most of these examples are fruit tarts, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the pie directly on the bottom of the oven.  The heat transfer is quicker and no soggy bottom.  However, this still may not be enough due to the quick time it takes to cook a quiche. Ohh and make sure you use regular bake (heat from bottom) not convection (heat from back and fanned).

If this is for guests, I would do a test run first.

(Edit:  Place the pie pan on the bottom of the oven)

Comment: I am quite sure that baking without the pan won't go well. The time between being firm and setting will be enough for the crust to collapse outwards, even if I managed to transfer it to the rack in one piece while it is still cold.

Comment: Ummm, I meant putting the entire pie and pan on the bottom.

Comment: The heat transfer between metal and pan is more efficient than between air and pan, sure, but I'm not sure that the bottom of the oven is actually well-heated. Ovens are more designed to keep the air hot.

Comment: I was a little skeptical myself.  But this tip came from a woman, as she put it, "baked pies and cakes for competitions 30+ years and has the knowledge". LOL!  Knowing her history, I tried it and by gosh it worked.  Try it, you just may be surprised.

Answer (score -1):

How about placing the pan on a heated pizza stone? That should sort it out.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, baking blind then adding the filling and baking again is not the best....the pastry can catch on the edges....too well done.  Personally I bake it all together until the filling has risen and is golden brown, leave to set for 10 mins then serve.  Don't forget to brush the top of your pastry cases with egg before cooking...to make it richer use cream instead of milk, you can also separate the whites from one of your eggs....use pancetta as appose to ham or bacon.  Also if you include onions, add brown sugar to caramise.